# service on nfs with sec=krb5i

Tags: nfs, httpd, kerberos, systemd

I'm trying to install nextcloud on an ArchLinuxARM box and would like to store uploaded data on an NFS server (debian testing). NFS server uses `sec=krb5i` to export shares.

I have SSSD running and NFS works smoothly for ordinary users.

However, I fail to make this work for user `http`.

I'm testing with

`sudo -u http ls /mount/http-folder`

Next, I tried to export http's keys to a keytab, but `sudo -u http KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME=/etc/httpd/conf/krb5.keytab ls /mount/http-folder` has same problem.

Update(2 - solved!):

The application needs to be aware of kerberos and honor `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME`.

Or better, when the client keytab is in its default location (as pointed out by Piotr P. Karwasz, that could be identified with `krb5-config --defcktname`) it will be picked up by `rpc.gssd` automatically.

```
[root]> su -l http -s /usr/sbin/bash
[http]> ls /mount/http-folder
ls: cannot open directory '/mount/http-folder': Stale file handle
[http]> krb5-config --defcktname
FILE:/var/lib/krb5/user/%{euid}/client.keytab
[http]> export KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME=/var/lib/krb5/user/http/client.keytab 
[http]> ls /mount/http-folder
ls: cannot access '/mount/http-folder': Permission denied

# note the difference (1)

[http]> $ kinit -t $KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME http
keytab specified, forcing -k
[http]> ls /mount/http-folder
this_is_www-data
[http]> exit

# solution:

[root]> mv /var/lib/krb5/user/http /var/lib/krb5/user/`id -u http`
[root]> su -l http -s /usr/sbin/bash
[http]> kdestroy  # (2)
[http]> ls /mount/http-folder
this_is_www-data
```

(1) not sure what causes this - according to kerberos docs it should use the first principal it finds in the client keytab file - the client keytab contains *only* the desired princial, so ... ? As Piotr P. Karwasz correctly points out, %{euid] is the *numeric* id, not the usename (bummer!), so client keytab is *not* in default location!

(2) make sure ticket cache is empty

So, problem solved. Thanks, Piotr!

Comment: Try the default location of client keytabs: `krb5-config --defcktname`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated question with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a process accesses you NFS mount, the kernel makes an upcall to **rpc.gssd** to establish the credentials. I didn't explore the upcall mechanism further, but I believe that **rpc.gssd** doesn't have access to the `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` variable or just ignores it and uses the default location.

The file `/var/lib/krb5/user/http/client.keytab` is not the default location on your system. Try replacing `http` with the numeric **uid** of user `http`:

```
getent passwd http | cut -d : -f 3
```